# How to refactor this GOTO (no resource deallocation involved)?

Tags: optimization, coding-style, conditional-statements, goto, control-flow

This is a simple control-flow GOTO question, nothing about resource allocation.

There are two levels of checking if a piece of data is "good".  If **and only if** it passes the first check, we do the second check.  If the data fails either test, we use a default value instead.

The second check involves a few steps with intermediate data, so we can't just put it in a short-circuited `||` condition.  Furthermore, if the second test passes, we use the output of the second test instead of the original data.

This is the inner loop in a real-time processing situation, so efficiency is very important.  We don't want to do any of the calculations more than once.

```
if (firstCheck(data)) {
    result = analyze(data);
    if (secondCheck(result)) {
        use_result(result);
    }
    else {
        goto FAIL;
    }
}
else {
FAIL:
    use_result(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

This GOTO seems to satisfy all my requirements with maximal efficiency.  I can think of some other ways to do it, but all would involve extra storage or conditionals.  I am wary of GOTOs though.  In fact, if I use this, it will be the first time I have ever used a GOTO.  So please, help me find the way out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` to go to next loop iteration

```
if (firstCheck(data)) {
    result = analyze(data);
    if (secondCheck(result)) {
        use_result(result);
        continue;
    }
}
use_result(DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Comment: Interesting that both answers use "tricks" to make it work: `continue` is basically a restricted `goto`, and C's "assignment is an expression" idiom is a hack-provoking language feature IMO.  Accepting this one because it gives me more flexibility with `analyze()` and `secondCheck()`, but upvoting both.

Answer (score 1):

Well we can fix this without much work, but using a goto in this way isn't necessarily bad behavior - e.g. the linux kernel uses this convention for doing error handling in only one spot as well and I think the code is quite clear as is.

Using exceptions to fix this is obviously one solution, but this does cost performance in the error case, so I assume that's out of the question.

So if you want to, this should be fine:

```
if (firstCheck(data) && secondCheck(result = analyze(data)) {
    use_result(result);
}
else {
    // fail
}
```

Comment: `use_result(result)` is gonna fail because result is not defined. Plus, OP don't want to analyze more then once.

Comment: Oh you're right, better fix that. I don't see where we're analyzing more than once though..

Comment: Now you're not analyzing more than once, but I was afraid of `use_result(analyze(data))` which was not used in your current code.

Comment: Where? I have only one call to analyze in there and the call sequence is equivalent to the given one: firstCheck, [analyze, secondCheck] if firstCheck true, [use_result] if secondCheck true. Ok we have to use a function for the second code block if it's larger than one statement, but with an inline function that's no loss.

Comment: You can reduce the performance hit of exceptions either by making an exception subclass which prevents its stack-trace from being filled in, or by creating the exception object just once, caching it, and then repeatedly throwing the cached exception.  In the case where you're using the exception just for flow control you don't care about the stack trace.

Comment: @MatthewCline interesting idea that. I remember having to rewrite some exception using code because it wasn't performant enough in a tight loop (with caching the exception object), but subclassing the exception to avoid the stack trace? No idea how much the compiler could optimize in that case then, but I'll have to try that sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You are not just using a goto. You are using a goto that goes into another scope. Much simpler:

```
if (firstCheck(data)) {
    result = analyze(data);
    use_result (secondCheck (result) ? result : DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
else {
    use_result(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Cleaner, no code duplication, and scalable:

```
int result = DEFAULT_VALUE;
if (firstCheck(data)) {
    int tmpResult = analyze(data);
    if (secondCheck (tmpResult))
        result = tmpResult;
}
use_result (result);
```